# How many permutations of the letters: DREAMORTEAM do not have identical consecutive letters?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I tried to do do this using inclusion-exclusion principle, and got something like this:

$ \frac{11!}{2!2!2!2!} -\binom{4}{1} \frac{10!}{2!2!2!}+\binom{4}{2} \frac{9!}{2!2!}-\binom{4}{3} \frac{8!}{2!} + \binom{4}{4}7!$

But I have no idea if it's correct. Can someone tell me if it's correct, and if it's not, why is it incorrect?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: This is totally tangential and purely friendly: was the “O“ in “DREAMORTEAM” intentional? Is this some kind of pun? $\ddot\smile$ I assume yes because of the “identical consecutive letters” part.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in the comments, your calculation is correct.